# Trouble making google chart responsive

Tags: html, charts, responsive-design, google-visualization, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to make my google chart responsive. The google chart is located in a bootstrap modal.

Code of javascript:

```
 var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "testChart.php",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
    }).responseText;


    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

    var options = {
        chart: {
            title: 'Values',
        },
        width: 900,
        height: 600
    };

    //var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    //chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
    chart.draw(data, options);

    $('#chartModal').modal("show");
```

Code of html:

```
<div id="chartModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Chart</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="chart_details">
            <div id="chart_div"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Image of chart in "phone-mode" now:

[image: chart in bootstrap modal resized]

*I've tried making the width and height values in javascript in percentages, but doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

the chart will follow the size of its container
but only when the container is visible

as such, need to wait until the modal has been shown,
before drawing the chart

listen for this event --> `'shown.bs.modal'`

see following working snippet...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    google.charts.load('current', {
      packages: ['corechart']
    }).then(function () {
      $("#myModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['x', 'y'],
          [0, 0],
          [1, 1],
          [2, 2],
          [3, 3]
        ]);

        var options = {
          chartArea: {
            // these options leave room for the title, axis-labels, etc...
            top: 16,
            left: 24,
            right: 16,
            bottom: 36,

            height: '100%',
            width: '100%'
          },
          height: '100%',
          width: '100%'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body test">
          <div id="chart_div"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```